# Join works in Azure SQL but fails with with R DBI connection: The multi-part identifier could not be found

Tags: r, sql-server, azure, dbi

I have a query that works perfectly in SSMS. But when running the query in R using the DBI package, I receive several multipart identifier errors: `The multi-part identifier: "rt.secondary_id" could not be bound`, `"rt.third_id" could not be bound`, and `"t2.important" could not be bound.`

```
select t1.[main_id]
    ,rt.secondary_id
    ,rt.third_id
    ,t1.[date_col]
    ,t2.important
from t1
inner join rt on t1.main_id = rt.main_id
inner join t2 on rt.main_id = t2.main_id
inner join (select t1.main_id, max(t1.date_col) as upload_time from t1 group by t1.main_id) AS ag ON t1.main_id = ag.main_id AND t1.date_col = ag.upload_time
```

The unique identifier in t1 is the combination of `main_id` and `date_col`, and this query finds the most recent entry in t1 for a given `main_id`.

Not exactly sure if my query is structured in a poor way or this is an R issue.  I've tried adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` to the query based on what I thought might be related issues elsewhere on stackoverflow, but no dice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what my issue was- silly (but time consuming) mistake on my part... but essentially, I was bringing my SQL query into R via `paste(scan(...), collapse = " ")`. I had a comment in my SQL query, `--`, which could not be read correctly by R. Deleting the comment OR switching the comment to `/* ... */` syntax fixes the problem.

Comment: I think many of us have been burned once or twice by something like this (I know I have). It's always frustrating ...